# How to create report with PDF using WCF Service in C#.net?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, pdf

I have created WCF Service. I have want to provide functionality to create Order Report and PDF of that Order Report.

Currently I have details of Order(OrderID, CustomerName, Product details etc). I want to create Report on the base of the order details and create PDF. I want to return that PDF in bytes to user who call the service.

So flow will be like this

```
1- User will provide Order details
2- Service function will create Report and PDF of it
3- Pass the PDF in bytes as return.
```

For step-2, I can use any open source tool which support in VS 2013. 
Can anybody suggest me steps or give me hint to start work on this?

Comment: Professor Google will help you find one of many such open source libraries. Choose one, play with it, and if you have a specific problem you can't solve, let us know! Good luck. https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=c-sharp%20open%20source%20pdf%20generator

Comment: @ShannonHolsinger I also want to generate report on the base of Order details. Then that report should be converted in PDF.

Comment: Any of those libraries should allow document creation from RTF, plain text, Word, or whatever source you'd like to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are using iTextSharp library in many projects.
Write a small prototype and try to include every case you have: e.g. horizontal lines across your document.

Comment: It is long process. You are asking me to design the PDF manually. Does it provide template same as Microsoft Word provide for Sales Invoice?

Comment: Hm...how will you create a report? If you have already have a technology to create reports and just want to print them by pdf automatically use server side installation of pdf creator. It will return the pdf.

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately I have just object of Order Table which has Order id, Date, customer, products details(list of product with qty, discount etc), owner details. First I need to create report, then PDF. Please suggest for both.

Comment: The pdf manually:  iTextSharp The pdf automatic if you have already a finished whatever document: PdfCreator Regarding your question about templates: I don't think that iTextSharp has predefiened templates but you can create your own template.